# Can't get jQuery to work in index.js in Blank Cordova App in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create a blank Apache Cordova App as shown in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm44U.png

Using the NuGet Package Manager, I've added jQuery to my project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH7co.png

From my basic understanding, adding jQuery through the NuGet Manager doesn't add a script tag to my index.html (or index.js) but instead get's packaged up in the Cordova.js file.

I've added the following basic link tag in my index.html `<a href="#" id="mylink">Link</a>`

However, if I try to reference that anchor tag using jQuery in my index.js file, I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

However, in the debug window, in the javascript console, I can use jQuery just fine to access elements. I am missing something basic here. ***Can someone explain why my jQuery is failing?***

Here are  my index.html and index.js files:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--
    Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed.      Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
    For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data:     gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';     media-src *">
<title>Office365Test3</title>

<!-- Office365Test3 references -->
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Test 3</p>
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="mylink">Link</a>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function () {
"use strict";


document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    $('#mylink').css('display', 'none');




};



function onPause() {
    // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state     here.
};

function onResume() {
    // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application     state here.
};
} )();
```

Comment: It's been a while, but last time I created a Cordova app, I still had to link to jQuery. Have you tried this?

Comment: I just did a quick test, and found that moving the jQuery files into the www/scripts directory and linking to them there from index.html seemed to work. Like I say, I'm a bit rusty with Cordova, and I'm not familiar with the `reference` tags in your index.js file, so I don't know if it's the recommended practice or not.

Comment: Thank you for the help Michael. I haven't yet tried that, I'll give it go a go when I get home. Thanks again.

Comment: Michael, you were spot on, that did the trick. I moved the jquery-2.1.4.min.js file into the www scripts folder and referenced it in index.html and no more jQuery issues. Thank you so much! I'm not seeing any options to mark your answer as the answer?

Comment: Glad it worked out, I've added my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your jQuery files into the `www/scripts` directory, and reference them from your `index.html` file. By default, NuGet places them in the `Scripts` folder in the project root, which doesn't seem to be accessible.